# Is there any way to display Rails' log files in the browser?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

This might be (read: probably is) a dumb question, but here goes...

Is there a simple, preferably non third-party, way to display Rails logs in the browser? It gets kind of old opening a log file, then closing it and re-opening it on the next error. It would be superfantastic to just to go `domain.tld/logs`, which would require user authentication, of course.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All you need is to open log file and put its content into browser.

Realted topic: [ruby: all ways to read from file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545068/ruby-all-ways-to-read-from-file).

Also you should know that your logs grow very fast, and it's not a good idea to show whole log in browser. You can just open last 100-200 rows. Related topic: [Reading the last n lines of a file in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754494/reading-the-last-n-lines-of-a-file-in-ruby)

Also you can try this solution: http://newrelic.com/. It is more complex and little oftopic, but quite useful.

Comment: It's so simple when someone else gives you the solution :)  Thank you, sir!

Comment: "All you need is to open log file and put its content into browser." Sorry. Didn't get what you meant?

Answer (score 12):

For reference, there is a very simple way to do this. However, you would want to protect this page with some sort of authentication/authorization.

**Controller:**

```
lines = params[:lines]
if Rails.env == "production"
  @logs = `tail -n #{lines} log/production.log`
else
  @logs = `tail -n #{lines} log/development.log`
end
```

**Log File View:**

```
<pre><%= @logs %></pre>
```

**View to display link:**

```
<%= link_to "log file", log_path(lines: 100) %>
```

**Routes:**

```
get 'logs/:lines' => "pages#log", as: "log"
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be a bit more robust to do `log/#{Rails.env}.log` instead of if-else?

Comment: @alexanderbird absolutely, today, I would

Answer (score 9):

I created a for this purpose called [browserlog](https://github.com/dieb/browserlog).

Installing is just a matter of adding the gem to the Gemfile:

```
gem 'browserlog'
```

Afterwards all you need is to mount the engine on the route you want:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  mount Browserlog::Engine => '/logs'
end
```

Once that's set up, accessing /logs/development (or production, test, etc) will show a window like this:

[image: browserlog_screenshot]
<sub>(source: [andredieb.com](http://andredieb.com/assets/images/browserlog1.png))</sub>

Answer (score -1):

[Pimp my Log](http://pimpmylog.com/) can be used to visualization many types of logs including Ruby on Rails.

It also includes the management of users and notification.

[Edited]

By default, the PimpMyLog does not support Ruby on Rails logs. It's necessary to implement the regex to works with it.

[/Edited]