# Ruby print last line of files where files are given from stdin re-direction

Tags: ruby

Want to run Ruby like this

```
cat *.txt |my_print_last_line.rb
```

And have the last line of each file printed (might do something interesting if I could first print)

The `ARGF` class seems promising to solve it.
Tried this:

```
ARGF.each do |line|
  last_line_of_file = line[last] 
  puts last_line_of_file
end
```

However `ARGF.each` seems to be one long string of all files concatenated rather than the individual files.

Comment: Why don't you `my_print_last_line.rb *.txt` instead?

Comment: @muistooshort won't work, `ARGF` also just concatenates the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with how `cat` handles multiple files. It just concatenates them:

```
$ echo 'foo' > foo
$ echo 'bar' > bar
$ cat *
foo
bar
```

This means that after issuing the `cat` command there's no way of telling where the individual files started and ended. If you would just invoke your script as `ruby my_print_last_line.rb *.txt` you would still have the same problem because using `ARGF` will also simply concatenate all files.

As an alternative, you could take the filenames as parameters to the ruby script to open and read the files directly in ruby:

```
ARGV.each do |file|
  puts IO.readlines(file).last
end
```

Then invoke your script like this:

```
$ ruby my_print_last_line.rb *.txt
```

If you are reading really large files, you may gain a significant performance benefit by using a `seek` based approach, as described by @DonaldScottWilde in [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754494/reading-the-last-n-lines-of-a-file-in-ruby).

Comment: How about When it it needs to be run recursively : for example find . -name "*.txt" |my_print_last_line.rb

Comment: That's not [recursive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)). Please be more specific where the problem is, should work as it is!

Comment: Running the Ruby on *.txt only expands files in the cwd,  what if I want a to run in on all files in the tree as would be produced by >find . -name "*.txt"

Comment: You can run the script via `find` using the `-exec` flag: `find . -name "*.txt" -exec ruby my_print_last_line.rb {} \;`

Comment: Running under windows from a dos prompt. Get the following errors. /test.rb: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('      test.rb: line 2: `  puts IO.readlines(file).last'  Ran it like this: find . -name "*.txt" -exec test.rb {} ;  The test.rb is the 3 lines of code you provided. BTW running Ruby 1.93

Comment: Sorry, i have no clue about windows to be honest.