# How do I start reading big file at specific line in ruby

Tags: ruby, file-io

I have a really big file and somehow new data is appended to the end of the file.
I only need to read the new data of this file. But now I have to read from the head of this file an scan the whole file.

Is there a good way to start read file from a specific line number?
Or is there another way to solve it around?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754494/reading-the-last-n-lines-of-a-file-in-ruby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `tail` command from your shell, and use that inside ruby, like this:

```
lines = `tail -n 10 your_file.txt`
```

You can also install a gem named `elif`, which basically works like a regular `File` module, but allows you to read the file backwards :)

```
gem install elif
```

Now, you can do something like this to get the last line from your file:

```
Elif.open('your_file.txt', &:gets)
```